# wilcox.test() on many combinations of columns

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table with approximately 400 columns and 800,000 rows. The columns represent samples and the rows represent CpG sites. Example data here:

```
require(data.table)
samples <- replicate(200,replicate(1000,runif(1)))
cpgs <- paste0('cpg',1:1000)
n <- c('cpg',paste0('sample',1:200))
data <- data.table(cbind(cpgs,samples))
colnames(data) <- n
```

I want to run a wilcox.test() on randomly selected columns of this data 1000 times. I've currently implemented this the following way, but it's very slow on large numbers of permutations.

```
cases <- paste0('sample',1:10)
controls <- paste0('sample',30:40)
data[,wilcox_p:=wilcox.test( as.numeric(.SD[,mget(cases)]), as.numeric(.SD[,mget(controls)]) )$p.value,by=cpg]
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this? My complete use case, where getCpGSites() is the function described above, is here:

```
iterations_vec <- 1:1000
labels <- paste0('sample',1:200)

permutations <- foreach(i = iterations_vec, .combine='rbind', .multicombine = TRUE ) %dopar% {
    
    case_labels <- sample(labels,num_cases,replace=FALSE)
    control_labels <- labels[!labels %in% case_labels]
    
    signature_cpgs <- getCpGSites(case_labels,control_labels)
    num_signature_cpgs <- length(signature_cpgs)
    
    out <- data.table('gene' = gene,
                      'iteration' = i,
                      'num_signature_cpgs' = num_signature_cpgs)
    return(out)
    
  }
```

Comment: `data <- data.table(cbind(cpg,samples))` gives "Error in cbind(cpg, samples) : object 'cpg' not found".

Comment: Oops, that should be 'cpgs' not 'cpg'. Will edit.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach, based on the tidyverse.  First, convert all your character data tonumeric, rtaher than delegating to your function.

```
library(tidyverse)

numericData <- data %>% mutate(across(where(is.character), as.numeric))
```

Now write a function to perform a Wilcoxon test on a randomly selected pair of columns

```
randomWilcox <- function(d) {
  cols <- sample(2:ncol(d), size=2, replace=FALSE)
  d1 <- d %>% select(cpg, all_of(cols))
  tibble(
    col1=cols[1],
    col2=cols[2],
    p.value=wilcox.test(d1 %>% pull(2), d1 %>% pull(3))$p.value
  )
}
```

Now use `lapply` to run the function 1000 times, with a very crude measure of speed:

```
startTime <- Sys.time()
lapply(1:1000, function(x) numericData %>% randomWilcox) %>% bind_rows()
endTime <- Sys.time()
# A tibble: 1,000 × 3
    col1  col2 p.value
   <int> <int>   <dbl>
 1    15   172  0.124 
 2    26    58  0.202 
 3   200    60  0.840 
 4   124    94  0.344 
 5   180   200  0.723 
 6   122   155  0.987 
 7   122   174  0.173 
 8    83   146  0.921 
 9   135    95  0.0605
10   168   174  0.0206
# … with 990 more rows
```

Each row of the output tibble contains the indices of the columns selected, and the p-value obtained from corresponding `wilcox.test`.

The time taken is about 13 seconds on my machine.  Is that quick enough?

```
endTime - startTime
Time difference of 13.1156 secs
```

**Edit**

Removing the intermediate data frame reduces the time taken to just over none seconds:

```
randomWilcox <- function(d) {
  cols <- sample(2:ncol(d), size=2, replace=FALSE)
  tibble(
    col1=cols[1],
    col2=cols[2],
    p.value=wilcox.test(d %>% pull(cols[1]), d %>% pull(cols[2]))$p.value
  )
}
```

Comment: Two questions: First, my use case is across multiple sets of columns (so in the example there are 10 'case' columns and 10 'control' columns, but in my actual use case the numbers of case and control columns vary a bit). Is this method still usable? Second, I have a character column of CpG names (cpg) that I want as my output, which is why I used as.numeric() in the function call. Is there a way to work around this column when type converting?

Comment: Q1: Rather than sampling two columns at random, just sample 1 control column and one control column.  Q2: I am confused.  Your column of CpG names contains 1000 entries.  The p-value from each Wilcoxon text is a single number.  How do you propose to these elements that have different dimensions?

Comment: Q1: I don't sample two columns at random, I sample 20 columns at random (in this example), 10 of which I want to test against the other 10. In my actual use case, this could be as many as 40 columns tested against 60. Q2: They don't have different dimensions, but they are different types (character, numeric). You mentioned that it was more efficient to convert everything to numeric before performing permutations, and I was wondering how to get around converting the 'cpg' column also.